# more value with the same name

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have 20 functions in jQuery, where one would do, making a div slide down and up again into place.

My question is:

How do I change this code so that it uses a named function, so I'm free for more function somewhere. Is it possible to cut down the code to one function in all with a name?

```
$('#top1').click(function() {
      $('#book3').slideDown('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
    $('#luk3').click(function() {
      $('#book3').slideUp('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });

    $('#top2').click(function() {
      $('#book4').slideDown('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
    $('#luk4').click(function() {
      $('#book4').slideUp('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
```

I am more function yet but will not write them all.

```
<div id="top3">
Opdater Password til absb.dk
</div>
<div id="book5">
    <h5>Updater adgangskode</h5>
    <form action="#" method="post">
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Adgangskode</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="pass" class="new"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Adgangskode gentag</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="gentag" class="new"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="opdater_pass" value="Opdater" class="new upload_boxxen"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST["opdater_pass"]))
        {
            $updater_pass = $mebe->updater_pass();
        }
        ?>
    </form>
    <div id="luk5">
        Luk
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what some of my content out

Comment: This is why functions are present in all languages, to counteract a problem like this

Comment: At the moment it's difficult to understand what you're asking.  If you can take another pass at your question to make it clearer, that would be great.

Comment: @ASGM he wants to essentially minimize the duplicated javascript code, as he apparently has 20 functions which just expand a DIV on click, so far, he is using seperate functions for each DIVs animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking to reduce the amount of code, so that you don't need to have a function for every ID.

Firstly you can reduce your code to something like this:

```
$('#top1, #top2, #top3').click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideDown('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});

$('#luk1, #luk2, #luk3').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().slideUp('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

I'd then try and give each 'top' and 'luk' a class, so you can just use:

```
$('.top').click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideDown('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});

$('.luk').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().slideUp('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Comment: `$('.top').click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideDown('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});

$('.luk').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().slideUp('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});`

Help me best!. :) good job! and thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

If I think I understand your question correctly, you could add a class to each one of your divs and then have your click function look at that instead.

So for example, you could have the following as a div:

```
<div id="top3" class="slider_toggle">Opdater Password til absb.dk</div>
```

You can then update your jQuery to use that class and then get the ID of the clicked div and slide that div up like you want:

```
$('.slider_toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).slideUp('slow', function () {
        alert("slide is complete");
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

I provided a working JS fiddle for you to look and see how I did it:
http://jsfiddle.net/BhuKM/